# influxdb cli bucket create on remote server

Tags: influxdb

I am trying to create an inFlux bucket on the command line (Debian) on my local business network remotely

`influx bucket create --description "Test Description" --host 192.168.1.102:8086 --name "cli test" --org 5a107188112648ba -t btQo_vgVRIs3DuGlIe7NXV33vsE4GCOB8XK68f_R5WiGGcn8wnrKNJ83-RcYiFcmP02-gJ-XnH2irLQnG3-Jpw==`

I get the following reply:
`Error: host URL "192.168.1.102:8086" is invalid: parse "192.168.1.102:8086": first path segment in URL cannot contain colon`

Do I have to create the bucket with a username and password? If so, how do I specify the username and password?

InFlux version is 2.6.1

Answer (score 0):

Solved,
I had to add http:// to the IP address like this:
`influx bucket create --description "Test Description" --host http://192.168.1.102:8086 --name "cli test" --org 5a107188112648ba -t btQo_vgVRIs3DuGlIe7NXV33vsE4GCOB8XK68f_R5WiGGcn8wnrKNJ83-RcYiFcmP02-gJ-XnH2irLQnG3-Jpw==`